# Should I index a Boolean Field with low 'True' cardinality MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, database-design

I have a MESSAGE table with 1M rows (and growing). Every query for messages involves selecting rows WHERE isRequest = True or WHERE isRequest = False, but never both. The vast majority of my queries are looking for isRequest = False. This table is written to extremely frequently and I need to maintain fast writes (as users love to send messages to each other with low latency). Also note that the MESSAGE table currently has no column indexes other than the primary key.

95% of the rows have isRequest = False and only 5% of rows have isRequest = True. **Is it more performant to index the isRequest boolean field in such a scenario?**

In addition, I understand that indexing columns consumes memory but is this overhead **equivalent** for all column  data types including, in my case, boolean values?

**Update:**

After further analysis with @Rick James we have come up with a new table scheme (*note all PKs are auto-inc so time relativity is discernible*):

```
MESSAGE (id=PK) (sender_id, recipient_id, conversation_id = FKs)
---------------------------------------------------------------
id  sender_id   recipient_id  message            conversation_id
1    1          2            "hows it going"   4
2    2          1            "great! hbu"      4
3    1          8            "hey man"         3
4    9          1            "please respond"  2
5    4          6            "goodnight girl"  1


CONVERSATION (id=PK) (userA_id, userB_id = FKs)
-----------------------------------------------
id  userA_id  userB_id
1   4          6            
2   1          9
3   1          8
4   1          2


USERCONVERSATION (id=PK) (userA/B_id, conver_id, lastMsg_id = FKs)
------------------------------------------------------------------
id   userA_id  userB_id   conver_id  lastMsg_id   isRequest
1    4         6          1          5            False
2    6         4          1          5            False
3    1         9          2          4            True
4    9         1          2          4            True
5    1         8          3          3            False
6    8         1          3          3            False
7    1         2          4          2            False
8    2         1          4          2            False
```

**Indexes:**

```
MESSAGE: index(id),
         index(conversation_id, id)

CONVERSATION: index(id), 

USERCONVERSATION: index(id),
       index(user_id, isRequest),
       index(user_id, lastMessage_id),
       index(conversation_id)
```

**Queries in application:**

*The following queries should be performant due to proper indexing as stated above. Please reach out if improvements can be made.*

To get latest 20 conversations (including the last message content and the other user's information) for a variable userID:

```
SELECT  T4.userB_id, T4.username, T4.profilePic, T4.conver_id,
        T4.message 
    (
        SELECT  T1.userB_id, T2.username, T2.profilePic, T1.conversation_id,
                T1.lastMessage_id
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  userB_id, conversation_id, lastMessage_id
                    FROM  rage.userconversation
                    WHERE  userA_id = {userID}
                      AND  isRequest=False
            ) AS T1
            LEFT JOIN  rage.user AS T2  ON T1.userB_id = T2.id AS T3
    )
    LEFT JOIN  rage.message AS T4  ON T1.lastMessage_id = T4.id
    ORDER BY  T4.id DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

Word explanation: Get 20 of the most recent USERCONVERSATION rows as the lastMessage is stored there. In order to find the 20 most recent for a given user, select all the rows with user_id = userID and sort by lastMessage_id DESC. This is accurate because message_id is auto-incrementing. Along with the last message we need to get some user data (profile picture, username) of the other user in the conversation. We achieve this by left joining.

**Result:**

```
RESULT (for userID = 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------
userB_id  username   profilePic  message            conver_id
8         John       8.jpg       "hey man"          3
2         Daisy      2.jpg       "great! hbu"       4
```

Then when the user taps on a conversation, since we have the conversation_id, we simply:

```
SELECT * FROM rage.message WHERE conversation_id={conver_id} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Hopefully since we indexed (conversation_id, id) the sorting is fast.

Comment: I have a similar situation, I believe it is best to index here.

Comment: Could you please explain yourself?

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097)

Comment: Please describe, in words, what your example is trying to do.  Perhaps it is looking for messages that went either direction between them?  But what is the `LEFT JOIN` doing?

Comment: @RickJames done

Comment: @Rage - How does `isRequest` fit into your example??

Comment: @RickJames some messages are being sent to recipients without permissions and therefore isRequest = True. This is only 5% of messages. Once permissions are acquired, all future and prior messages are switched to isRequest = False

Comment: @Rage - Do you need to add a column to the sample data?  And fill it in with suggested values for that flag?

Comment: Didn't want to clutter the example but I just filled it in. I linked the SHOW CREATE TABLE below.

Comment: We  still can't cut & paste & run from your post. Put everything needed to ask in your post as text. Repeating your code in English is not helpful.--When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. A "basically" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".  Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean.

Comment: @RickJames I have created the schema we have talked about and implemented it into the application. Before I deploy the new schema/logic and suffer down time I would like to make sure I have not left out any crucial indexes. Do you have any recommendations? Or Should I start a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here.  From what you describe, one of the following two seem appropriate:

- A *clustered* index where the first key is `IsRequest`.
- A partitioning scheme that includes `IsRequest`.

Another possibility is are two separate tables.

However, because I doubt that your queries are returning 95% of the rows -- or even 5% -- there are undoubtedly other filters.  It may be more important to create indexes for those filters rather than for the boolean flag.

Comment: You're right I certainly have other filters for the query but they are foreign key filters which are indexed but you're right, they are not indexed together in this table. I have supplied a sample query above. Filters: sender_id(FK), recipient_id(FK), isRequest. Perhaps I should index all three together?

Answer (score 0):

Use a composite index.  Let's see the entire `WHERE` clause to give you accurate details.

Example

```
WHERE IsRequest = True
  AND UserId = 12345
```

would benefit from

```
INDEX(IsRequest, UserId)
```

(and it does not matter which order you put the column names in, nor does it matter whether it is True or False.)

**Your Example**

- `OR` wrecks the use of indexes
- `UNION` between two queries might avoid `OR`.
- No index is useful for the query as you wrote it.
- There will be two *nested* table scans.

**Maybe**

(I don't know if the following does the same thing.)

```
( SELECT  m1.id, m1.sender_id, m1.recipient_id, m1.message ...
    FROM  myapp_message AS m1
    LEFT JOIN  app_message AS m2
         ON  m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
        AND  m1.id < m2.id
    WHERE  m2.id IS NULL
      AND  m1.sender_id = {userID}
      AND  m1.isRequest = False
    order by  id desc
    LIMIT  20
) UNION ALL (
SELECT  m1.id, m1.sender_id, m1.recipient_id, m1.message ...
    FROM  myapp_message AS m1
    LEFT JOIN  app_message AS m2
         ON  m1.recipient_id = m2.recipient_id
        AND  m1.id < m2.id
    WHERE  m2.id IS NULL
      AND  m1.recipient_id= {userID}
      AND  m1.isRequest = False
    order by  id desc
    LIMIT  20 
)   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
```

If you will be paginating, see this:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union

**Closer**

```
SELECT  m...
    FROM
      ( SELECT xid, MAX(mid) AS mid
        FROM
        (
          ( SELECT  recipient_id AS xid,
                    MAX(mid) AS mid      -- The last message TO each recipient
                FROM  WHERE sender_id = 1234  -- FROM the user in question
                GROUP BY  recipient_id
                ORDER BY 2 DESC   -- ("2nd column")
                LIMIT  20                        
          )
          UNION ALL
          ( SELECT  sender_id AS xid,
                    MAX(mid) AS mid      -- The last message FROM each sender
                FROM  WHERE recipient_id = 1234  -- TO the user
                GROUP BY  sender_id
                ORDER BY 2 DESC
                LIMIT  20
          )
        ) AS y
        GROUP BY xid       -- yes, repeated
        ORDER BY mid DESC  -- yes, repeated
        LIMIT 20           -- yes, repeated
      ) AS x
    JOIN messages AS m  ON m.mid = x.mid
```

With both of these indexes:

```
INDEX(sender_id, recipient_id, mid)
INDEX(recipient_id, sender_id, mid)
```

One `INDEX` is for each subquery.  Each is optimal, plus "covering".

(I don't see the relevance of `isRequest`, so I left it out.  I suspect that if the column is needed it can be added to the indexes without loss of efficiency -- if put in a proper position.)

Comment: Unfortunately my queries are slightly more complex than one WHERE clause. The example query above is used to show the user's most recent conversations. It returns the last message sent from his 20 most recent conversations. Updated the post ^

Comment: Two nested table scans is very "not good". Is there any way to achieve the same query with increased performance? I need to get the last message from the 20 latest conversations from the user. Let me know if my context is unclear. I wish I had the source code to Instagram's direct messaging.

Comment: @Rage - What is the diff between `myapp_message` and `app_message`?

Comment: Typo, just fixed

Comment: I think you may be on to something but the query does not compile in MySQL

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY xid       -- yes, repeated           ORDER BY mid DESC  -- yes, repeate' at line 18

Comment: @Rage - I made another stab at it.  If that still gives an error, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can test it myself.

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216185/discussion-between-rage-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 0):

For this query, and perhaps others, it would be good to have another column in the table.  It would a unique number, say "conversation_id", that is derived from unique pairs of sender and recipient.

A crude way (but not necessarily the optimal way) is to derive it somehow from distinct values of this ordered pair:

```
(LEAST(sender_id, recipient_id), GREATEST(recipient_id, sender_id))
```

Then `INDEX(conversation_id, id)` would probably be the key to the query being discussed.  At that point, we can add back in the discussion of the boolean.  I would suspect that this would ultimately be the optimal index:

```
INDEX(conversation_id, isRequest, id)
```

(or possibly with the first two columns swapped).

Comment: You certainly may be on to something. As I see it, the conversation_id column would be great to query for a specific conversation. However, in the context of my application, I do not have conversation_ids, I am instead searching for the 20 latest messages (each from a unique conversation). Perhaps this would include a new table, CONVERSATION, that stores each user's conversations. Columns: conversation_id, user_A, user_B. The aforementioned query then would first be to get all the conversation_ids the user is involved in, and then query for the max message _id from the message table?

Comment: Perhaps an extension to this solution would be to have a CONVERSATION table as stated earlier as well has having a lastMessage_id that is a foreign key to a message_id in the MESSAGE table. Every time someone in an existing conversation sends a message, not only does it add this message to the MESSAGE table, it also updates the conversation's lastMessage_id foreign key so that the conversation now points to the newly most recent message. Now the query would be: get me all the conversations this user_id is involved in. And we would also have a pointer to the lastMessage.

Comment: What would the optimal indexes look like for such a strategy?

Comment: I would add `conversation_id` to the current table.  It would be initialized by some clumsy query like what we are working on, then a rather simple query would keep it going.  Having another table would be `conversation_id` (the auto_inc PK), plus the 2 users.  But you still end up with 2 joins and a union (or something) to make the query in question be fast.

Comment: Yeah, the link to the `last_message_id` probably works.  But back to the boolean -- think through its impact on updating `last_message_id`.

Comment: It would then be appropriate to delete the boolean field isRequest and add it to the CONVERSATION table as entire conversations fall under a single isRequest value. What do you mean by the impact on updating last_message_id? This would only involve selecting the conversation_id row O(log n) and updating the FK whenever a message is sent. As for updating the isRequest boolean, it would be the same process. Any performance issues I have not anticipated?

Comment: Also, let's think about indexes. In the MESSAGE table it seems that only two indexes are needed: (PK), (conversation_id) as the queries are only: get me the lastMessage_id or get me all the messages in this conversation_id ordered by PK descending limit 20. In the CONVERSATION table querying to update a specific conversation is taken care of by indexing the PK. The difficult part is to get all the user's conversations. But what sort of index would enhance a query that selects all rows where userA_id = userID OR userB_id = userID? Perhaps INDEX(userA), INDEX(userB) and split the query into two?

Comment: For "get all the user's conversations"...  Yet another table, this has just 3 columns and a PK across them: (user, conv, msg).  (Maybe add a timestamp of the message).

Comment: I just updated the question and consolidated our thoughts, please take a look. In addition, is sorting message_id DESC or lastMessage_id DESC helped by the above indexes?

Comment: This Q&A has gooten too long.  Please, start a new question with (1) the latest `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`, (2) the important `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`, (3) ask if the indexes are sufficient.